# Can't figure out why line of code throws exception

Tags: c++, oop, exception, segmentation-fault, pass-by-reference

```
class Graph //part of graph.h, functions go in graph.cpp (functions not shown)
{
private:
    vector< list<Edge> > adjList; //Vector of Lists (sort of like a 2D array)
public:
    Graph(){}
    ~Graph(){}
    class Edge
    {
    public:
        Edge(string vertex, int weight)
        {
            m_vertex = vertex;
            m_weight = weight;
        }
        ~Edge(){}
        string m_vertex;
        int m_weight;
    };

    vector < list < Edge > >& get_adjList(){return adjList;}
    //Other functions....

};
```

I am trying to access the adjList data structure in another file known as MinPriority.cpp (the names not really important).  The entire program works inside of graph.cpp (I can build the structure fine and print it inside of graph.cpp) but I can't seem to access the adjList from another file (that uses a completely different class) using the below code:

```
void MinPriority::referenceVector()
{
    Graph graph;
    vector< list<Graph::Edge> >& adjList = graph.get_adjList();
    cout << "adjList test: " << adjList[0].front().m_vertex << endl;
}
```

For simplicity lets just add element `Edge("A", 0)` into `vector< list<Edge> > adjList;`  that will make the Vector of lists contain string A at `adjList[0].front().m_vertex` and 0 at `adjList[0].front().m_weight`.  I'll then print it from WITHIN the file graph.cpp and it will tell me that there is 1 Edge containing the weight 0 and the vertex A. (Good! It's supposed to do that!)

The real problem starts in void `MinPriority::referenceVector()` as soon as I hit `vector< list<Graph::Edge> >& adjList = graph.get_adjList();` The terminal tells me this:

```
A
ADDING A TO VECTOR
(A, 0) -->
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=0043CE11
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=61276EC0 edi=611A1E9B
ebp=0028AA68 esp=0028AA50 program=C:\cygwin\home\Ryan\311\P5Dec16\Graph.exe, pid 6188, thread main
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0028AA68  0043CE11  (00000000, 00000000, 0028AB08, 004026E3)
0028AA78  0043CEAD  (00000000, 00000000, 0028ABB0, 0028AB7C)
0028AB08  004026E3  (0028AC20, 0028ABB0, 20010100, 004011C1)
0028AC68  00401583  (00000001, 0028AC90, 20010100, 612757A2)
0028ACF8  6100763A  (00000000, 0028CD78, 61006C50, 00000000)
End of stack trace
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This leads me to my question, what is wrong with `vector< list<Graph::Edge> >& adjList = graph.get_adjList();` and how could I fix it?  Note: I tried to include as much information as I thought you guys might need, please leave a comment if you need anything else.

EDIT: I ran it in GDB again and this time for some reason it gave me more information!  ill post it below!

```
IN MAIN
A
ADDING A TO VECTOR
(A, 0) -->

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0043ce11 in std::list >::begin (
    this=0x0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:600
600           { return this->_M_impl._M_node._M_next; }
(gdb) where
#0  0x0043ce11 in std::list >::begin (
    this=0x0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:600
#1  0x0043cead in std::list >::front (
    this=0x0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:716
#2  0x004026e3 in MinPriority::createArray (this=0x28abe0,
    targetVertex=0x28ab70) at MinPriority.cpp:59
#3  0x00401583 in main () at MSTapp.cpp:39
(gdb)
```

Comment: Have you checked `adjList.size()` and  `adjList[0].size()`?

Comment: Ill check that real quick

Comment: It outputs 0, so yeah, for some reason it is not passing anything by reference.

Comment: Print the size of your member in `get_adjList()`, maybe your member hasn't been initialized correctly.

Comment: the seg fault happens at:  `cout << "adjList test: " << adjList[0].front().m_vertex << endl;`

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the point. `adjList` is empty. Therefore, `graph.adjList` is empty. Check whether you correctly add the `Edge` to your list. The reference part is fine, but I believe you never actually fill your list.

Comment: it tells me that adjList.size() is zero inside of the get_adjList function.

Comment: I am going to fetch the code that makes "A".

Comment: here it is: (not sure how to format it in comments)
`void Graph::set_array(string vertex)
{
    cout << "ADDING " << vertex << " TO VECTOR" << endl;
    adjList.resize(adjList.size() + 1);
    adjList[adjList.size() - 1].push_back(Edge(vertex, 0));
}`  this function takes in the string vertex (which is A in this case) increases the size of the adjList by 1 (so we can use the next line) then inserts A in adjList[size - 1] which is 0.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43656/discussion-between-zeta-and-user3040019)

Answer (score 3):

As long as your constructor doesn't automatic add edges to your adjacency list, it's going to be empty. Therefore, you're trying to access an edge on an empty graph:

```
void MinPriority::referenceVector()
{
    Graph graph;  // << empty graph
    vector< list<Graph::Edge> >& adjList = graph.get_adjList(); // << empty list

    //   accessing an empty list       vvv      will result in access violation
    cout << "adjList test: " << adjList[0].front().m_vertex << endl;
}
```

You need to fill your graph before you access its list. Also, check whether the given list/vector contains the element you want to access before actually accesing it. More likely, you want to operate on a graph, therefore something like

```
void MinPriority::referenceVector(Graph & graph)
{
    vector< list<Graph::Edge> >& adjList = graph.get_adjList();

    /* ... */
}
```

could be what you actually had in mind.